# Tcl's foreach not setting variables

Tags: foreach, set, tcl, uplevel

I'm redefining Tcl's `set` command to allow multiple assignments at once. However, once I try to use the variables, it reports an "undefined variable" error. Here are the two ways I've tried so far:

```
proc set args {
    uplevel foreach {*}$args break
}
```

```
proc set {l1 l2} {
    uplevel foreach $l1 $l2 break
}
```

I performed an `llength` on `$args` and it did report a list of two elements. I'm quite confused about this behavior.

I'm calling it like so:

```
set {a b c d} {e f g h}
set {a s d f} {q w e r t y}
```

---

**Edit:*

Did a bit more tinkering with it. I found a way to make it work (for the most part, because extra values are silently discarded, but that's irrelevant to the original question), but I'm still confused about WHY this way worked but the others didn't:

```
proc set {l L} {
    uplevel foreach [list $l] [list $L] break
}
```

Comment: The first "foreach {*}$args break" from calling "set {a b c d} {e f g h}" is expanded to "foreach a b c d e f g h break". Which causes a=b, c=d, e=f, and g=h.

Comment: Perhaps you know this, but you can achieve the same result by doing `lassign {a b c d} e f g h`.

Comment: @sharvian, but why so? Isn't `$args` a list with all the arguments passed to the callee? In which case, the passed arguments are two lists, which when "unpacked", should be expanding into two lists again.

Comment: @ColinMacleod, indeed. I didn't use `lassing` because it doesn't consume all the values if they're in excess, but returns them. I wanted the new set to consume everything. But I could work around that for sure.

Comment: @LuisLavaire I think "uplevel" also expands {...}, just like "eval" and {\*}. So in your first "uplevel foreach {\*}$args break", the $args is expanded twice.

Comment: Consider using `tailcall` instead of `uplevel`. That doesn't do argument concatenation...

Comment: I'd recommend turning the uplevel script into a single list as argument: `proc set {l L} { uplevel [list foreach $l $L break] }` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`uplevel`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/uplevel.html) joins its arguments *as if they had been passed to [`concat`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/concat.html)*, which among other things, says

> If all of the arguments are lists, this has the same effect as concatenating them into a single list.

So your first version becomes

```
foreach a b c d e f g h break
```

leaving `a` set to *b*, `c` set to *d*, and so on. Your second version ends up doing the same; the two lists are flattened out and their elements become individual arguments to `foreach`. The third version, wrapping the arguments in `list`, becomes your intended

```
foreach {a b c d} {e f g h} break
```

the outer list is stripped, but the inner ones remain.

---

As an aside, I would use a different name than `set`, or define it in a non-global namespace, unless you also intend to also support the single-argument version of `set` that returns the current value of a variable. Way less confusing that way.

Comment: I appreciate your time. As a follow-up, do you have any idea of what's the rationale behind this `uplevel` behavior, or better, any source where I can read about it?

Comment: It's the same as `eval`, `after`, and a few other commands.

Comment: It's been like that since forever. Was probably done by John Ousterhout in the very first version before anyone really understood what a bad idea that was. It's left as it is because we don't know how much user code actually depends on the behaviour and a workaround that makes it safe (with `list`) isn't too hard. The modern version of the workaround didn't happen until 8.5 and it took a bit for people to grasp what they had...